# Use of an audio transformer - is this safe?

Tags: transformer, audio

I'm new to audio things. I tried google but I couldn't find any information on basic use of audio transformer or isolation transformer.

I have a microphone that will be connected to a pre-amplifier. The pre-amplifier output will be for the line-in jack of a desktop PC. The cable length is 2-3 meters.

Is this the correct use of the transformer, or do I just remove transformer and connect the pre-amplifier out direct to line-in?

I'm worried about 'floating ground' on the secondary side.

[image]

Comment: If it is a desktop PC and properly plugged in, the transformer secondary won't be floating.

Comment: Why do you think you need a transformer? How is your preamp powered?

Comment: pre-amp is powered by a PoE device.

Comment: @ArielN You may want to *have a reason* for a transformer. There are a few truly good papers to read: [Hofer's *Transformers in Audio Design*, 1986](https://www.technicalaudio.com/pdf/Jensen_Transformers/Jensen_Application_Notes_and_Papers/Transformers_in_Audio_Design_Hofer_SVC_1986.pdf), [Whitlock's *Design of High-Performance Balanced Audio Interfaces*](https://sound-au.com/articles/balanced-interfaces.pdf), and [this preserved website at Elliot's](https://sound-au.com/articles/balanced-2.htm).

Comment: If the preamp is a PoE device, it must be a properly designed PoE device with a galvanic isolation for PoE input with a floating supply. And then there is no problem. But we also don't know who designed your pre-amplifier and if it has a properly designed power supply.